2 Youtube channels in the same account, one says I can earn money with Youtube and the other says monetization isnt available for my location (?)
I have several youtube channels in the same account. One of the accounts says I can earn money with Youtube, the other says monetization isnt available for my location. How is this possible? Is it a bug or something?
